# how to open the web sent by rich push notification outside the apps

Tags: iphone, ios

now im doing the push notification on iphone by using xcode. When i sending the message/notification to the user that contain URL for the user to open it, so  the user will receive the notification and message that contained URL and open it in the webview in the apps. Is it possible to open that URL outside the apps by chrome or safari?

what are coding need to modified in order to connect that clicked URL to open the browser outside the apps?

this is the coding that make the webview is open when clicked on the link.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = [request URL];


    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"ua"]) {
    if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) || (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther)) {
            [UAInboxMessage performJSDelegate:wv url:url];
            return NO;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make static method.

```
+ (void)openBrowser:(NSString *)url {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

and then call it anywhere

```
[className openBrowser:@"http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/ios-sdk-open-other-app-from-our-app.html"];
```

If you have rich text in your url then you can make encoding with it.

```
NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *resultStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

Comment: Thank for the respons. but the problem is the URL is sent by using Rich Push Message by Urban Airship, which means, the URL not provide or write in the xcode coding. How do i connect that second coding to these URL that sent by Urban Airship Push Message?

Comment: oh thanks..i think that will give me some idea..but, i still stuck to connect the URL sent from rich push notification in order to open web browser. do you have any idea to solve this problem with custom key? thanks for your time.

Comment: can you paste your rich text?

Comment: - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"ua"]) {
    if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) || (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther)) {
            [UAInboxMessage performJSDelegate:wv url:url];
            return NO;
        }

Comment: sorry,u can see the coding more clear on the question above.thanx!

Answer (score 1):

With the use of this code you can open a link to safari browser just pass your link instead of provided

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.daledietrich.com"]];
```